# Using GMail for domains but have old email address linked to another Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-account

We just switched email hosts to GMail Apps, but we already have few GMail accounts. Is there any way to transfer these into the Gmail hosting?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transfer the already existing GMail accounts, but you do can transfer/share all the emails, contacts, Documents, Calenders to the new account.

Comment: Adding HOW to transfer/share those emails, contacts, docs, calendars to the new account would be more helpful.